# How do I dynamically create a UDF in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` where I want to create multiple UDFs dynamically to determine if certain rows match. I am just testing one example right now. My test code looks like the following.

```
//create the dataframe
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("t","t"), ("t", "f"), ("f", "t"), ("f", "f")).toDF("n1", "n2")

//create the scala function
def filter(v1: Seq[Any], v2: Seq[String]): Int = {
  for (i <- 0 until v1.length) {
    if (!v1(i).equals(v2(i))) {
      return 0
    }
  }
  return 1
}

//create the udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val fudf = udf(filter(_: Seq[Any], _: Seq[String]))

//apply the UDF
df.withColumn("filter1", fudf(Seq($"n1"), Seq("t"))).show()
```

However, when I run the last line, I get the following error.

```
:30: error: not found: value df
       df.withColumn("filter1", fudf($"n1", Seq("t"))).show()
       ^
:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[String]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
       df.withColumn("filter1", fudf($"n1", Seq("t"))).show()
                                               ^
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Note, I am on Scala v2.11.x and Spark 2.0.x.

On another note, if we can solve this "dynamic" UDF question/concern, my use case would be to add them to the dataframe. With some test code as follows, it takes forever (it doesn't even finish, I had to ctrl-c to break out). I'm guessing doing a bunch of `.withColumn` in a for-loop is a bad idea in Spark. If so, please let me know and I'll abandon this approach altogether.

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("t","t"), ("t", "f"), ("f", "t"), ("f", "f")).toDF("n1", "n2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val fudf = udf( (x: String) => if (x.equals("t")) 1 else 0)

var df2 = df
for (i <- 0 until 10000) {
  df2 = df2.withColumn("filter"+i, fudf($"n1"))
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, the entries in your columns are strings not sequences

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a UDF that takes an arbitrary number of columns (e.g. `$"n1"`,`$"n2"`,...,`$"n10"`) and values (e.g. "t", "f", ..., "t"), and inside the UDF, see if `n1="t" and n2="f" ... n10="t"`.

Comment: This type of "filtering" can easily be done serially with `df.where("n1='t' and n2='f' ... and n10='t').count` but that approach is non-parallelizable, such filters will have to run sequentially each time incurring a Spark action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose **"t"** in `lit()`

```
df.withColumn("filter1", fudf($"n1", Seq(lit("t")))).show()
```

Try registering UDF on `sqlContext`.

[Spark 2.0 UDF registration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#udf-registration-moved-to-sqlcontextudf-java--scala)

Comment: could you show an example with an arbitrary number of columns and lits?

Comment: `Seq(lit("t"), lit("f"))`. If we don't use `lit` for strings, it will treat as coulmn name.